# Getting the below err while trying to run the query on DB2 db

Tags: sql, db2

I get this err

```
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=((select * from ( select rownumber() over(;BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT;<delete>, DRIVER=3.50.152
```

when I run the below query:

```
((SELECT ORGANIZATION.ORGNAME AS ORGNAME
        ,SUBSCRIPTION.ID AS SUBSCRIPTIONID
        ,SUBSCRIPTION.NUMBEROFAVAILABLESEATS AS AVAILABLESEATS
    FROM SUBSCRIPTION SUBSCRIPTION
        ,ORGANIZATION ORGANIZATION
        ,CUSTOMER CUSTOMER
        ,CUSTOMERACCOUNT CUSTOMERACCOUNT
    WHERE ORGANIZATION.ISDELETED=0
      AND SUBSCRIPTION.DELETED=0
      AND CUSTOMERACCOUNT.ID=SUBSCRIPTION.CUSTOMERACCOUNTID
      AND CUSTOMER.ISDELETED=0
      AND CUSTOMERACCOUNT.CUSTOMERID=CUSTOMER.ID
      AND CUSTOMER.PARTYID=ORGANIZATION.ID
      AND ISLIMITEDSEAT=1 
UNION ALL 
  SELECT ORGANIZATION.ORGNAME
        ,SUBSCRIPTION.ID AS SUBSCRIPTIONID
        ,-1 AS AVAILABLESEATS
    FROM SUBSCRIPTION SUBSCRIPTION
        ,ORGANIZATION ORGANIZATION
        ,CUSTOMER CUSTOMER
        ,CUSTOMERACCOUNT CUSTOMERACCOUNT
    WHERE ORGANIZATION.ISDELETED=0
      AND SUBSCRIPTION.DELETED=0
      AND CUSTOMERACCOUNT.ID=SUBSCRIPTION.CUSTOMERACCOUNTID
      AND CUSTOMER.ISDELETED=0
      AND CUSTOMERACCOUNT.CUSTOMERID=CUSTOMER.ID
      AND CUSTOMER.PARTYID=ORGANIZATION.ID
      AND ISLIMITEDSEAT=0
 ) as results
  order by ORGNAME
) with ur
```

Hibrnate decoded query :

```
"((select * from ( select rownumber() over(order by ORGNAME)with ur) as rownumber_, ORGANIZATION.ORGNAME AS ORGNAME,SUBSCRIPTION.ID AS SUBSCRIPTIONID,SUBSCRIPTION.NUMBEROFAVAILABLESEATS AS AVAILABLESEATS FROM SUBSCRIPTION SUBSCRIPTION,ORGANIZATION ORGANIZATION,CUSTOMER CUSTOMER,CUSTOMERACCOUNT CUSTOMERACCOUNT WHERE ORGANIZATION.ISDELETED=0 AND SUBSCRIPTION.DELETED=0 AND CUSTOMERACCOUNT.ID=SUBSCRIPTION.CUSTOMERACCOUNTID AND CUSTOMER.ISDELETED=0 AND CUSTOMERACCOUNT.CUSTOMERID=CUSTOMER.ID AND CUSTOMER.PARTYID=ORGANIZATION.ID AND ISLIMITEDSEAT=1 UNION ALL SELECT ORGANIZATION.ORGNAME,SUBSCRIPTION.ID AS SUBSCRIPTIONID,-1 AS AVAILABLESEATS FROM SUBSCRIPTION SUBSCRIPTION,ORGANIZATION ORGANIZATION,CUSTOMER CUSTOMER,CUSTOMERACCOUNT CUSTOMERACCOUNT WHERE ORGANIZATION.ISDELETED=0 AND SUBSCRIPTION.DELETED=0 AND CUSTOMERACCOUNT.ID=SUBSCRIPTION.CUSTOMERACCOUNTID AND  CUSTOMER.ISDELETED=0 AND CUSTOMERACCOUNT.CUSTOMERID=CUSTOMER.ID AND CUSTOMER.PARTYID= ORGANIZATION.ID AND ISLIMITEDSEAT=0) results order by ORGNAME)with ur ) as temp_ where rownumber_ <= ?"
```

Comment: Please edit your title and body

Comment: I think you have too many unnecessary parentheses.

Comment: I tried removing that even then it was the same

Answer (score 0):

I formatted the query a little bit. I am not sure if the syntax is correct though. The `order by` looks a little bit lonely (doesn't have a matching select) and I am not sure what the `with` is supposed to do.

```
((SELECT ORGANIZATION.ORGNAME AS ORGNAME, 
    SUBSCRIPTION.ID AS SUBSCRIPTIONID,
    SUBSCRIPTION.NUMBEROFAVAILABLESEATS AS AVAILABLESEATS 
  FROM SUBSCRIPTION SUBSCRIPTION,
       ORGANIZATION ORGANIZATION,
       CUSTOMER CUSTOMER,
       CUSTOMERACCOUNT CUSTOMERACCOUNT 
  WHERE ORGANIZATION.ISDELETED=0 AND SUBSCRIPTION.DELETED=0 
    AND CUSTOMERACCOUNT.ID=SUBSCRIPTION.CUSTOMERACCOUNTID 
    AND CUSTOMER.ISDELETED=0 
    AND CUSTOMERACCOUNT.CUSTOMERID=CUSTOMER.ID
    AND CUSTOMER.PARTYID=ORGANIZATION.ID 
    AND ISLIMITEDSEAT=1 
UNION ALL 
  SELECT ORGANIZATION.ORGNAME,
         SUBSCRIPTION.ID AS SUBSCRIPTIONID,
         -1 AS AVAILABLESEATS 
  FROM SUBSCRIPTION SUBSCRIPTION,
       ORGANIZATION ORGANIZATION,
       CUSTOMER CUSTOMER,
       CUSTOMERACCOUNT CUSTOMERACCOUNT 
  WHERE ORGANIZATION.ISDELETED=0 
    AND SUBSCRIPTION.DELETED=0 
    AND CUSTOMERACCOUNT.ID=SUBSCRIPTION.CUSTOMERACCOUNTID 
    AND  CUSTOMER.ISDELETED=0 
    AND CUSTOMERACCOUNT.CUSTOMERID=CUSTOMER.ID 
    AND CUSTOMER.PARTYID=ORGANIZATION.ID 
    AND ISLIMITEDSEAT=0
 ) results order by ORGNAME
)with ur
```

Comment: With UR means with uncomitted Read

Answer (score 0):

```
the following thing worked for me :

SELECT RESULTS.ORGNAME,
       RESULTS.SUBSCRIPTIONID,
       RESULTS.AVAILABLESEATS FROM(
                                     (SELECT ORGANIZATION.ORGNAME ,SUBSCRIPTION.ID AS SUBSCRIPTIONID,-1 AS AVAILABLESEATS
                                      FROM SUBSCRIPTION SUBSCRIPTION,ORG` v`ANIZATION ORGANIZATION,CUSTOMER CUSTOMER,CUSTOMERACCOUNT CUSTOMERACCOUNT
                                      WHERE ORGANIZATION.ISDELETED=0`enter code here`
                                        AND SUBSCRIPTION.DELETED=0
                                        AND CUSTOMERACCOUNT.ID=SUBSCRIPTION.CUSTOMERACCOUNTID
                                        AND CUSTOMER.ISDELETED=0
                                        AND CUSTOMERACCOUNT.CUSTOMERID=CUSTOMER.ID
                                        AND CUSTOMER.PARTYID=ORGANIZATION.ID
                                        AND SUBSCRIPTION.ISLIMITEDSEAT=0)
                                   UNION ALL
                                     (SELECT ORGANIZATION.ORGNAME ,SUBSCRIPTION.ID AS SUBSCRIPTIONID, SUBSCRIPTION.NUMBEROFAVAILABLESEATS AS AVAILABLESEATS
                                      FROM SUBSCRIPTION SUBSCRIPTION,ORGANIZATION ORGANIZATION,CUSTOMER CUSTOMER,CUSTOMERACCOUNT CUSTOMERACCOUNT
                                      WHERE ORGANIZATION.ISDELETED=0
                                        AND SUBSCRIPTION.DELETED=0
                                        AND CUSTOMERACCOUNT.ID=SUBSCRIPTION.CUSTOMERACCOUNTID
                                        AND CUSTOMER.ISDELETED=0
                                        AND CUSTOMERACCOUNT.CUSTOMERID=CUSTOMER.ID
                                        AND CUSTOMER.PARTYID=ORGANIZATION.ID
                                        AND SUBSCRIPTION.ISLIMITEDSEAT=1))AS RESULTS
```

Comment: In this case you should be able to remove the outer select and it's as Results and get the same output. Looks like you make it more complicated then necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Your original problem may have been due to the placement of the parentheses, but it became difficult to unravel due to the length and complexity of what was going on.

I'll put several suggestions together, giving you a much shorter query, which should also be significantly faster, and easier for the next person to understand.

Let's look at what's going on.  You've got two nearly identical SELECTs being glued together.  Suppose we mesh them back into a single SELECT.

A little bit of logic, in the form of a CASE expression will be a lot less work overall than two SELECTS that get merged and sorted back together.

Unless you are creating an abbreviation, there's no point repeating every table name:

```
  FROM SUBSCRIPTION SUBSCRIPTION,
```

It is often deemed clearer to the next person if you specify the join conditions in the FROM clause, rather than the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT ORGANIZATION.ORGNAME,
       SUBSCRIPTION.ID         AS SUBSCRIPTIONID,
       CASE WHEN SUBSCRIPTION.ISLIMITEDSEAT = 1
            THEN SUBSCRIPTION.NUMBEROFAVAILABLESEATS
            ELSE -1 
        END                    AS AVAILABLESEATS
  FROM ORGANIZATION
  JOIN CUSTOMER
    ON  CUSTOMER.PARTYID = ORGANIZATION.ID
  JOIN CUSTOMERACCOUNT
    ON  CUSTOMERACCOUNT.CUSTOMERID = CUSTOMER.ID
  JOIN SUBSCRIPTION
    AND SUBSCRIPTION.CUSTOMERACCOUNTID = CUSTOMERACCOUNT.ID
  WHERE ORGANIZATION.ISDELETED=0
    AND SUBSCRIPTION.DELETED=0
    AND CUSTOMER.ISDELETED=0
    AND SUBSCRIPTION.ISLIMITEDSEAT IN (0,1)
```

If SUBSCRIPTION.ISLIMITEDSEAT is a flag that can only be 0 or 1, then drop that last line.